# Get HTML from file using SIMPLE HTML DOM

Tags: php, html, arrays, string, dom

this is part of my HTML:

```
<div class="info">
    <ul class="links">
    </ul>
    <h1>TEXT #1</h1>
    <ul class="names">
       <li>
       <img src="images/flags/flag_1.gif" alt="USA"  />
       <h3>TEXT #2</h3>
       </li>
       <li>
       <img src="images/flags/flag_34.gif" alt="CZ název"  />
       <h3>TEXT #3</h3>
       </li>
    </ul>
```

I am using Simple html DOM praser and i try to get that 3 text (TEXT #1, TEXT #2, TEXT #3)

My try of PHP code:

```
$html = file_get_html('file.txt'); 
$ret = $html->find('ul[class="links"]');   //nazov filmu


foreach ($ret as $translate) {
    $translate = $translate->innertext;
    }   
    echo "$translate";
```

Ideal result should be:

```
echo "$translate[0]";  //TEXT #1
echo "$translate[1]";  //TEXT #2
echo "$translate[2]";  //TEXT #3
```

Comment: Why aren't you doing that in JavaScript?

Comment: i did 90% in PHP already, just few more like this missing

Answer (score 0):

I assume that "file.txt" refers to the above piece of HTML...

Looks to me like your find('ul[class="links"]') does not contain anything (as per the sample code). Are you trying to select all tags with the type ?

Comment: You are right, HTML code up in my first post is part of file.txt. I just dont know how to select something like this from HTML. So yea my PHP code can be totaly wrong

Answer (score 0):

## PHP

```
$titles = array();
$html = file_get_html('file.txt'); 
$html = $html->ownerDocument;
$lists = $html->getElementsByTagName("ul")
foreach($lists as $list):
    if($list->getAttribute('class') == "links"):
        $list = $list->ownerDocument;
        $h3 = $list->getElementsByTagName('h3');
        
        foreach($h3 as $title)
            $titles->push($title);
    endif;
endforeach;

echo $titles[0];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer mate, but it throw me this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Array' (T_ARRAY)

Comment: @Andurit Try with this code (I edited my answer). It's been a while since I coded some PHP content, so I had teh array initialization part wrong. It's fixed now.

Comment: hey, its still throwing some errors:
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object